# documet.getElementBy is is not passing thae value

Tags: javascript, html

My javascript code is:

```
    document.getElementById('district').value =  dist.long_name "this line is passing the value"
    document.getElementById('city').value =  route.long_name "this doesn't"
```

[View the image of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hu7fE.png)

My HTML is:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>District</label>
    <select id="district" class="form-control">
        <option id="district" selected='selected' style="display:none;"><label id="district"></label> </option>
        <option>Thrissur</option>
        <option>Kozhikode </option>
        <option>Palakkad </option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>City</label>

    <select id="city" class="form-control"> 
        <option id="city" selected='selected' style="display:none;"><label id="city"></label> </option>   
        <option>opt1</option>
        <option>opt2 </option>
        <option>opt3 </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I got below error, how can i fix that:

> documet.getElementBy is is not passing the value

Comment: `city` is a `<label>` which has no `.value`-attribute. (Ah, you used the id `city` three times - that's not allowed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have unique ids in HTML.

```
 <select id="city" class="form-control">
```

and

```
<label id="city"></label>
```

is not acceptable.

Comment: How about option elements containing HTML ..?

Comment: you should not have same id in entire HTML document.